# How to synchronize changes in Active Directory with SharePoint profile info

Tags: 2013

I recently had an incident where the email details of a SharePoint user were changed in Active Directory. These changes were not transferred into SharePoint and I had a problem in one of my web parts which uses the SPUser object to get the users email address.

Is there a way to configure SharePoint 2013 to synchronize such data automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check job definitions.

> Central Administration --> Monitoring --> Review Job Definitions

[image]

Also you can start synchronization manually

> Central Administration --> Application Management --> Manage Service
>   Application --> User Profile Service Application

[image]

If still not succeeded, you can use following PowerShell script for this specific user. I use these script usually when users did not synchronized.

```
#Get web
$web=Get-SPWeb "http://www.mspportaladdress.com" 
#Synch
$web|Set-SPUser -identity "i:0#.w|mydomain\user.name" -SyncFromAD
#Check user
$web | Get-SPUser -Limit All | Where-Object {$_.UserLogin -like '*user.name*'} | select UserLogin,DisplayName
#If still no success, create new user with same username and then synch
$web | New-SPUser -UserAlias "i:0#.w|mydomain\user.name"
$web|Set-SPUser -identity "i:0#.w|mydomain\user.name" -SyncFromAD
```